# Почему вылетает код c ошибкой?

Tags: java, android, камера

Вот такой не сложный код

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static Context context;
private CameraManager mCameraManager = null;
public static final String LOG_TAG = "mistake";
private final int CAMERA1 = 0;
private final int CAMERA2 = 1;
private CameraHelper[] myCameras = null;
private Button mButtonOpenCamera1 = null;
private Button mButtonOpenCamera2 = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    context = this;

    //получаем обьект камера менеджер
    mCameraManager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);

    // Получения списка камер в устрйстве
    String[] cameraList = new String[0];
    try {
        cameraList = mCameraManager.getCameraIdList();
    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (cameraList.length > 0) {
        for (String cameraID : cameraList) {
            System.out.println("cameraID: " + cameraID);
            int id = Integer.parseInt(cameraID);

            // создаем обработчик для камеры


            ВОТ ТУТ ---->>>    myCameras[id] = new CameraHelper(mCameraManager, cameraID, getApplicationContext());


            // выводим инормацию по камере
            myCameras[id].viewFormatSize(ImageFormat.JPEG);
        }
    }else System.out.println("FATAL FATAL FATAL FATAL");

    mButtonOpenCamera1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_open_camera1);
    mButtonOpenCamera2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_open_camera2);

    mButtonOpenCamera1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (myCameras[CAMERA2].isOpen()) myCameras[CAMERA2].closeCamera();
            if (myCameras[CAMERA1] != null) {
                if (!myCameras[CAMERA1].isOpen()) myCameras[CAMERA1].openCamera();
            }
        }
    });

    mButtonOpenCamera2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (myCameras[CAMERA1].isOpen()) myCameras[CAMERA1].closeCamera();
            if (myCameras[CAMERA2] != null) {
                if (!myCameras[CAMERA2].isOpen()) myCameras[CAMERA2].openCamera();
            }
        }
    });
}
}
```

**и вот что пишет**

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                               Process: com.example.aleksey.camera2api, PID: 17915
                                               java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.aleksey.camera2api/com.example.aleksey.camera2api.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to write to null array
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
                                                Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to write to null array
                                                   at com.example.aleksey.camera2api.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:48)
                                                   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
```

Все проверил, должно быть все в порядке... что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Давайте вчитаемся в сообщение об ошибке:

> Attempt to write to null array

Вы объявили массив `cameraList` и инициализировали его `null`'ом. Прежде чем заносить в него элементы, надо распределить под массив память:

```
if (cameraList.length > 0) {
  myCameras = new CameraHelper[cameraList.length];
  ...
  myCameras[id] = new CameraHelper(mCameraManager, cameraID, getApplicationContext());
```